# Static field doesn't update

Tags: java, eclipse, static

There were times I changed a static field in my program, but when the program ran it would still get the old data. Even though I rebuild the workspace it wouldn't work. 
I use Eclipse. Does the compiler cache the constant values? How do I avoid this problem?

```
Class Container {
    public static String message = new String("original");
}

Class B {
    public void printString() { System.out.println(Container.message); }
}
```

When run the program, it will print out "original". Later I change Container.message to "changed", my program will still print out "original" even I have already built the workspace. That's weird to me.

Comment: can you please share the code? it is difficult to answer your question without looking at the code.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @user2542027: Code posted. Thanks

Comment: @ChathurangaTennakoon: Code posted. Thanks

Comment: hmmm...never had a similar issue before. Maybe you have another class "Container" somewhere in your packages?

Comment: @Ricky You may need to make sure that you compile and re-generate your classes. Check the timestamp of the class you are running to be sure that it is up-to date with the code you have.

Comment: This is not valid Java. `Class` is lower case `class`.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "Later I change Container.message"?  Did you change the variable initialization or do you have other code that chages the value of the variable?  If it is the latter see Juned Ahsan's answer.

Answer (score 3):

### Inlining

**Fields with `static` and `final` modifiers are inlined by compiler. Fields with only `static` modifiers are not inlined.**

Let's have two classes

```
class A {
    static final String X = "test";
}

class B {
    public static void main (String... args) {
        System.out.println(A.X);
    }
}
```

compile them, remove `A` class, and run `B` class

```
javac A.java B.java
rm A.class
java B
```

It prints `test`.

String from `static`, `final` field was inlined into `B` class.

---

If we remove `final` modifier from `X` field, this example will fail.

```
class A {
    static String X = "test";
}

class B {
    public static void main (String... args) {
        System.out.println(A.X);
    }
}
```

compile them, remove `A` class, and run `B` class

```
javac A.java B.java
rm A.class
java B
```

and we get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: A
    at B.main(B.java:3)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: A
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

**To avoid problem of stale inlined values recompile all the sources at once.**

### Class loaders

Another problem may be observed if `A` class is loaded with two different class loaders. This will result in two copies of `A` class. Changing value of `static` field in one will not be visible to the code referencing `static` field of another.

### Compiler issues

**Be informed that Eclipse uses it's own Java compiler that behaves differently from JDK compiler.**

If you have a problematic class. Decompile it

```
javap -c B.class
```

and check if it accesses the field you want

```
3: getstatic     #3                  // Field A.X:Ljava/lang/String;
```

or was it inlined

```
3: ldc           #3                  // String test
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are having totally wrong perception about the static fields. Static fields are class variables i.e. all the objects will be sharing one copy of the application. But static fields are not preserved by the JVM for different runs of the program. So expecting that if you set some value of static field in one run then you will get the same value of the field is a totally wrong notion.

If you want to preserve the values then go for serialziation but even that is to store the state of object and not really meant for static fields.

Comment: I think he is talking about `static final` constants, and he changed their value in the code.

Comment: I don't think this is the question. I think he means he changes "original" to "changed" in the code and it still prints "original".

Comment: When I wrote my comment the question was just the first 3 lines, so I had to guess a little. I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

can you try the below code. it is perfectly working for me.

```
class  MainClass {

    public static void main(String a[]){
        //before changing the value
        System.out.println(" before changing the value ");
        B b = new B();
        b.printString();

        //changing the value
        Container.message = "changed";
        System.out.println(" after changing the value ");
        b.printString();
    }
}


class Container {
    public static String message = new String("original");
}

class B {
    public void printString() { System.out.println(Container.message); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes in Eclipse, specially in old versions (I haven't had this problem with Eclipse 4.x). Try to clean the generated `.class` and build them again (`Project -> Clean...`). Also make sure `Project -> Build Automatically` is checked so the compiler is invoked automatically every time you change something. If this does not work try restarting Eclipse (`File -> Restart`).